# GTest linker errors on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, ubuntu-20.04

I have the following errors on Ubuntu 20.04:

```
[1/1] Linking CXX executable bin/project_2022_matrix_tests
FAILED: bin/project_2022_matrix_tests 
: && /usr/bin/c++ -g  CMakeFiles/project_2022_matrix_tests.dir/CException.cpp.o CMakeFiles/project_2022_matrix_tests.dir/tests/CException_unit_tests.cpp.o CMakeFiles/project_2022_matrix_tests.dir/tests/main_unit_tests.cpp.o -o bin/project_2022_matrix_tests -L/home/username/.conan/data/gtest/cci.20210126/_/_/package/71c983c52942eb4756e4bd60e4cbec9fd7557e5d/lib -Wl,-rpath,/home/username/.conan/data/gtest/cci.20210126/_/_/package/71c983c52942eb4756e4bd60e4cbec9fd7557e5d/lib  -lgtest_main  -lgmock_main  -lgmock  -lgtest  -lpthread  -lpthread && :
/usr/bin/ld : CMakeFiles/project_2022_matrix_tests.dir/tests/CException_unit_tests.cpp.o : in the function « testing::AssertionResult::AppendMessage(testing::Message const&) » :
/home/username/.conan/data/gtest/cci.20210126/_/_/package/71c983c52942eb4756e4bd60e4cbec9fd7557e5d/include/gtest/gtest.h:357 : undefined reference to « testing::Message::GetString[abi:cxx11]() const »
/usr/bin/ld : CMakeFiles/project_2022_matrix_tests.dir/tests/CException_unit_tests.cpp.o : in the function « testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<CException*, decltype(nullptr)>(char const*, char const*, CException* const&, decltype(nullptr) const&) » :
/home/username/.conan/data/gtest/cci.20210126/_/_/package/71c983c52942eb4756e4bd60e4cbec9fd7557e5d/include/gtest/gtest.h:1529 : undefined reference to « testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) »
/usr/bin/ld : CMakeFiles/project_2022_matrix_tests.dir/tests/CException_unit_tests.cpp.o : in the function « testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<char*, decltype(nullptr)>(char const*, char const*, char* const&, decltype(nullptr) const&) » :
/home/username/.conan/data/gtest/cci.20210126/_/_/package/71c983c52942eb4756e4bd60e4cbec9fd7557e5d/include/gtest/gtest.h:1529 : undefined reference to « testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) »
/usr/bin/ld : CMakeFiles/project_2022_matrix_tests.dir/tests/CException_unit_tests.cpp.o : in the function « testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int, int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&) » :
/home/username/.conan/data/gtest/cci.20210126/_/_/package/71c983c52942eb4756e4bd60e4cbec9fd7557e5d/include/gtest/gtest.h:1529 : undefined reference to « testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool) »
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(project_2022_matrix_tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

if(EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
    conan_basic_setup()
else()
    message(WARNING "The file conanbuildinfo.cmake doesn't exist, you have to run conan install first")
endif()

find_package(GTest REQUIRED)

include_directories(.)

enable_testing()


add_executable(project_2022_matrix_tests
        CException.cpp
        CException.h
        CMatrix.cpp
        CMatrix.h
        CIndexableMatrix.h
        main.cpp)

add_executable(project_2022_matrix_tests_tests
        CException.cpp
        CException.h
        tests/CException_unit_tests.cpp tests/main_unit_tests.cpp tests/CMatrix_unit_tests.cpp)

target_link_libraries(project_2022_matrix_tests_tests gtest)
```

I have to say this works on CLion on macOS but for some reasons, not on Ubuntu...
If you need/want more information, please ask.

Thanks for your future reply.

Comment: https://github.com/shapelets/khiva/issues/67

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. OMG. I saw this, I tried it but It didn't work but I just had to change to "libstdc++11" instead of "libc++11". Thanks for your help and your patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the solution that was posted as a comment, just edit the `.conan/profiles/default` and change the line `compiler.libcxx` to set the value to `libstdc++11`.